# How to reset the VPS server to original state using SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, cpanel, vps, whm

My client recently purchased a VPS server and started configuring the WHM/cPanel related settings and unfortunately mis configured it (added a wrong DNS/ip details/and cpanel settings.) to an extent that its not reconfigurable through WHM login.

Although, the SSH connectivity is intact and works fine so far. Now, I would like to know if there is a way to reset the VPS back to its original state so that we can start configuring the WHM login again.

additional info : This is a linux host and I am able to login via ssh as root and operate. As far as I understood from my client we have added wrong domain name,some 5 Ips.

Thanks in advance.
Please let me know if you need any additional information from my end.

Answer (score 1):

Try to login your server through WHM with http://serverip:2086 URL and removed your domain which you have added wrong and delete the IP's from WHM,

And if you want to reinstall your VPS, Than you will have contact your VPS provider. They will reinstall your server so that you can start it again.